# Оптимизации обёрток примитивных типов для дженериков

Tags: оптимизация, java, generics

В Java параметром шаблонного класса не может служить примитивный тип; вместо этого используются обёртки наподобие `Integer`. Но такой подход влёчёт за собой накладные расходы в  виде лишних переходов по ссылкам, лишним нагрузкам на менеджер памяти и на Gargabe Collector.

Всё действительно так плохо, и написание собственного `ArrayListForInt`, содержащего внутри настоящие примитивные `int`'ы, сможет ускорить работу программы? Или же стандартный `ArrayList<Ingeter>` в байт-коде будет выглядеть достаточно оптимизированным, чтобы об этом не беспокоиться?

Comment: у тебя паранойя?

Comment: @Gorets, паранойя — это профессиональное качество любого программиста.

Comment: ну не знаю... я думаю... что надо думать логически, а лучше аналитически, а не ходить с фольгой на голове, сидеть под впнкой, через прокси и пытаться оптимизировать фраперы, не умея еще нормально кодить...

Comment: @Gorets, спасибо. Возможно, когда-нибудь я учту ваши советы и обращусь к психологу.

Comment: почитайте в доках java core про автоупаковку и автораспаковку. Будите удивлены.

Comment: Когда-то смотрел: скорость сортировки массива int и Integer (не  ArrayList) различается раза в 4. Хотя, м.б. это из-за вызова компаратора.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, это может сильно ускорить работу программы и снизить потребление памяти в ряде случаев. Писать их не надо, их уже очень много написано: [Trove](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/html/overview.html), [OpenHFT](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Koloboke), [HPPC](https://github.com/carrotsearch/hppc) и т. д. Там не только списки, но и, например, специальный `Map` из `int` в `double` и т. д.

Answer (score -1):

Немного ответа по вопросу =)
Лезем вот сюда [Integer.java](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/Integer.java.html) и смотрим на 659 строчке конструктор.

```
public Integer(int value) {
   this.value = value;
}
```

Comment: Что вы хотите этим сказать?

Comment: то что в враппере и так есть настоящие примитивы инта, а своим псевдоклассом вы только усложните читаемость/понимаемость/рефакторинг кода

Comment: То, что внутри `Ingeter` хранится `int` -- это очевидно из слова wrapper. Но даже это не спасает нас от того, что на каждый `int`, который мы положим в `ArrayList`, придется создать по одному экземпляру класса `Ingeter`.

Comment: вот статейка по этому поводу =)
http://habrahabr.ru/post/134102/

Answer (score -1):

а вы вообще задумывались зачем эти wrapper'ы ?

самой JVM они не нужны вообще. эти обертки нужны только для програмиста, - для того чтоб облегчить ему работу: jvm может неявно конвертировать их автоматически в обе стороны. кроме того они нужны для использования в коллекциях и в качестве параметризированых типов.

если б обертки нужны были JVM то скорее за все код самих классов был бы примерно таким:

```
class SimpleTypeContainerBean
{
   // set of fields for the int value
   private int intValue = 0;
   private boolean isInt = false;

   // constructor for int type
   public SimpleTypeContainerBean

   // getter and setter for int type
   public void setIntValue(int value) {
       this.intValue = value;
       this.isInt = true;

   }
   public int getIntValue() throws IllegalAcessException {
       if (!isInt) {throw new IllegalAcessException("field type is not int");}

       return intValue;
   }

   // здесь точно такой же код только для остальных примитивов
}
```